# I am getting an error Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading while updating to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, updates, 22.04

I am getting an error:

```
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading while updating to 22.04.
```

Here are the packages which seem to give trouble:

```
jammy 1.3~jammy-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.3~focal-1]
libvkd3d-shader1/jammy 1.3~jammy-1 i386 [upgradable from: 1.3~focal-1]
libvkd3d1/jammy 1.3~jammy-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.3~focal-1]
libvkd3d1/jammy 1.3~jammy-1 i386 [upgradable from: 1.3~focal-1]
vkd3d-compiler/jammy 1.3~jammy-1 i386 [upgradable from: 1.3~focal-1]
```

I am from India and using ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in as the  download link.

I used the below commands to try and upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

When I am using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` command. It gives me the below  prompt:

```
(Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.)
```

Thanks  for answering my query  ,
Nmath  has  provided  me a  resolution and  aplogies  for asking  question with incomplete  details  ,Yes  I  am currently  using 20.04 and  wish to upgrade  to 22.04 and  as  suggested  by
Nmath I  will wait for 22.04.01 version

Comment: Have you fully updated Ubuntu 20.04? What exact command did you use before you got these errors? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1422937/edit) and add all these information.

Comment: I wonder if you attempted to update from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04? I unwittingly tried that yesterday and discovered you are not supposed to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.  After that the only way i was able to resolve it was to do a clean install of 22.04 -- I had already backed all my data up so it worked relatively well -- didn't lose anything.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full outputs of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to your question. There's no need to give us partial errors or partial output-- you have plenty of room! Also tell us what release you are upgrading *from*. 21.10 is already EOL so you're past the date of the supported upgrade path. And the release upgrade from 20.04 isn't available yet and won't be until 22.04.1 is released. So there really aren't any supported upgrades at this time. Please be thorough and complete. If we have to guess at details, your question may be impossible to answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: The `-d` flag is a particularly bad idea. Check the manpage to see what it does. Hint: It does not do what you seem to want.

Comment: The question is currently unanswerable without guessing; it lacks key data. [Edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1422937/edit) to include the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `sudo apt upgrade`.

Answer (score 4):

In order to run do-release-upgrade none of the installed packages can be in 'upgradable' state. Easiest way is to temporarily remove them and install after upgrade.

Comment: +1 This is a wise move when the packages are from a non-Ubuntu source: A PPA or third-party repository. In this case, the OP's packages are indeed from a non-Ubuntu source. Returning your system to as close to stock condition as possible increases the likelihood of a successful release-upgrade.